# How do I make certain properties not serialized when cloning?

Tags: .net, serialization

I'm utilizing this guide [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23832/Implementing-Deep-Cloning-via-Serializing-objects) to allow me to clone certain objects in my project.  I have one object that has a property that references a particular object.  This particular object is from another library that I'm utilizing and is generated based off of the settings of my object.  The problem is that when I go to copy my objects, everything goes crazy because it tries to copy EVERYTHING.  Does anybody know how I can make this particular property ignored so that I can have it generate it itself upon cloning based on its settings?

I'm using VB.NET so all .NET answers are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can apply the [`[NonSerialized]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) attribute to any field you don't want to be serialized.

Comment: For clarity, this attribute was intended for use with binary serialization (though a few custom serializers respect it). For XML serialization, use [XmlIgnore] to accomplish the same end. DataContract serialization, whether XML or JSON, is "op-in"; you have to decorate the members you DO want serialized with [DataMember], so simply don't decorate the ones you want ignored.